# cannot resolve reference to bean 'jmsconnectionfactory' when using spring boot + spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I had a problem i'm using hornetq using spring boot and had to create a jmschannel in spring configuration using spring integration `<int-jms:channel id="jmsChannel"  queue-name="${spring.hornetq.embedded.queues}" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory">
        <int-jms:interceptors><int:wire-tap channel="logger"/></int-jms:interceptors>
    </int-jms:channel>`

This is working fine in local when loading with undertow, when deployed the war to Jboss it is throwing up saying bean named jmsConnectionFactory not found, any help is greatly appreiciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is nothing to do with the Spring Integration, but only Spring Boot stuff, which is called [deployable war](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file):

> The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass and override its configure method. This makes use of Spring Framework’s Servlet 3.0 support and allows you to configure your application when it’s launched by the servlet container. Typically, you update your application’s main class to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
```